# How can i encrypt my oauth post request for salesforce withut using signpost,scribe type library

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, salesforce, authorization, google-oauth

i want sample basic code for encrypting my oauth 2.0 post requests which will work with multiple apps like google,salesforce etc.

I already tried this code for salesforce authorization but its giving me bad request error. I was trying to sign oauth post request but got confused in oauth 1.0 and 2.0 -

```
public String getAuthorizationUrl() {
        LOGGER.debug("SalesforceUtility - getAuthorizationUrl");
        try {
        String baseUrl = "?response_type=code" + "&client_id="
    + this.clientSecrets.get("client_id")  + "&redirect_uri="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.clientSecrets.getString("redirect_uri"), "UTF-8");

String authorize_url = this.clientSecrets.get("auth_uri")
                    + baseUrl ;
computeSignature(baseUrl,client_secret);
        LOGGER.debug("SalesforceUtility - AuthorizationUrl" + authorize_url);
            return authorize_url;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception getAuthorizationUrl", e);
            throw new BusinessException(e,
                    BusinessErrorCode.SALESFORCE_AUTH_URL);
        }

    }
private static String computeSignature(String baseString, String keyString) {

        SecretKey secretKey = null;

        byte[] keyBytes = keyString.getBytes();
        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA1");

        Mac mac;
        try {
            mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
               mac.init(secretKey);

                byte[] text = baseString.getBytes();

                return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(mac.doFinal(text))).trim();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new SystemException(SystemErrorCode.SALESFORCE_UNSUPPORTED_ENCODING_EXCEPTION);
        } 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up the protocols. OAuth 2 doesn't use signatures. (OAuth1 does).

The Authorize request needs `response_type`, `client_id`, `redirect_uri` and `state` typically. (There are other params too like `scope`, but not always).

When using `response_type=code` you get a `code` from the Authorization Server (e.g. Salesforce, Google). Then you use the `/token` endpoint to exchange the code for a token. That endpoint uses the `client_secret`.

(An overview of the protocol is described here: https://auth0.com/docs/protocols#1)

Comment: I know all this. I am not talking about oauth_signature as param in oauth 1.0. I am asking how can i sign my whole post request  to salesforce endpoint url before sending it. As right now any one can see the client secret as plain text in saml tracer as post params.

Comment: You might want to rephrase/re-write your question. Not very clear what you are trying to do. In any case, signing will not prevent visibility of a secret. You might want to encrypt it. 

Also, client _secrets are never meant to be sent from user agents. They are  used in server side calls.